# Scraping other elements from a tag in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriver

The script on the webpage reads:

```
<td class="bc bs o" data-bk="B3" data-odig="7.5" data-o="13/2" data-hcap="" data-fodds="7.5" data-ew-denom="4" data-ew-places="5"><p>7.5</p></td>
```

I want to extract the 'data-bk' and 'data-odig' values for all td tags in the driver in Selenium. I know that every td tag has 'data-bk' and 'data-odig' values but I don't know what they are ("B3" "7.5") for each tag. I want to print the list of 'data-bk' values ("B3" etc.). I tried the following:

```
answer = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td[data-bk]')
print(answer.text)
```

But this does not work

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of `data-bk` and `data-odig` from all `td` tags

First you need to use
`find_elements_by_css_selector`() which will return `list` of elements and then you need to `iterate`

Secondly to get the `attribute value` you need to use `element.get_attribute("attributename")`

---

**Code**:

```
Databk=[item.get_attribute("data-bk") for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td[data-bk][data-odig]")]
DataOdig=[item.get_attribute("data-odig") for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td[data-bk][data-odig]")]
print(Databk)
print(DataOdig)
```

This will return list of `data-bk` and `data-odig`

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@data-bk="B3"]')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td[data-bk="B3"]')
```

you can use css or xpath

xpath syntax is

```
//tag[@attribute="attribute-value"]
```

CSS syntax is

```
tag[attribute="attribute_value"]
```

**

## so you can use any attribute not only id or name

**